# Which kind of Relationship should i give between the Tables in Sequelize when i do multiple inner join which depends on 3 tables

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-auto

```
const data = await MatchModel.findAll({
attributes: ['MatchUID', 'TournamentID', 'ScheduleDate', literal('(DATE_SUB(ScheduleDate,INTERVAL M.TimeDelay SECOND)) AS ScheduleDateOriginal'), 'HomeUID', 'AwayUID', literal('IFNULL(T.Team, T.FeedTeam) AS HomeTeam'), literal('IFNULL(T1.Team, T1.FeedTeam) AS AwayTeam'), literal("IFNULL(T.TeamLogo, '') AS HomeLogo"), literal("IFNULL(T1.TeamLogo, '') AS AwayLogo"), literal('IF(IFNULL(JSON_LENGTH(LineupOut), 0) > 0,1,0) AS LineupOut'), 'DelayMinute', literal("IFNULL(M.DelayMessage, '') AS DelayMessage"), ['T.FeedTeamName', 'HomeTeamFullName'], ['T1.FeedTeamName', 'AwayTeamFullName'], 'ScoreCard', 'TimeDelay', 'TimeDelayStatus', 'ShowMegaLable', 'IsInLeagueLeaderboard', 'MaxPrize', 'MaxPrizeGameName'],
            include: [{
              model: TournamentTeamModel,
              required: true,
              as: 'HomeTeam'
            },
            {
              model: TeamModel,
              required: true,
              as: 'T'
            },
            {
              model: TournamentTeamModel,
              required: true,
              as: 'AwayTeam'
            },
            {
              model: TeamModel,
              required: true,
              as: 'T1'
            }]
          })
          return resolve({ success: true, data })
```

**How can i give Relationship in above models, i have faced error of relationship i had try all the possible relation between all these table. But still not get any specific idea. so give me appropriate solution for solve above problem**

Comment: Where are the tables, their fields? please be more specific.

Comment: 1. You used 5 tables in the query instead of 3 mentioned in the title 2. Please describe in the post how these tables are related in terms of 1:1, 1:N, N:1, N:M